# Shairplay drops frames

Tags: pulseaudio, shairplay

I had shairplay (a rewrite of shairport) running fine with ALSA on my RPi.

Then I installed PulseAudio and some other programs and now it's dropping frames all the time and produces only stuttering sound fragments that might as well be complete noise.

Any ideas how to fix this?

EDIT: PulseAudio is indeed the culprit. Unless I find a way to mute specific apps with ALSA I *do* need PA, though. Surely PA should be able to play nice with ShairPlay?

Comment: Try disabling pulseaudio temporarily, I think it is often a culprit.

Comment: Disabling pulseaudio does in fact fix things. But that is not a solution, because I need pulseaudio to mute/unmute specific apps.

Comment: Yeah, it does fill a certain niche, e.g. multiplexing.  But...my experience is it can also create unresolvable problems.  Maybe I haven't made enough effort with it, it is certainly [quite complex](http://www.freedesktop.org/wiki/Software/PulseAudio/Documentation/User/).  So I don't have a real answer for you.  To be fair though the onus is more on shairplay to play nice with PA, even if PA is a bit of a jerk.